# Is there an example of memory IL rewriting (Profiler API)?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, clr, jit

I saw that the profiler API can do that. Do anyone know an example except this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17275/Really-Easy-Logging-using-IL-Rewriting-and-the-NET Cause I can't even compile it. I'm very interested in this.

Comment: Have you read [the referenced article by Aleksandr Mikunov](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but that looks like it's for the old version of the CLR.

Answer (score 1):

[David Broman's CLR Profiling API Blog: Creating an IL-rewriting profiler](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032259/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2007/03/06/creating-an-il-rewriting-profiler)

This blog contain lot of information with regard to IL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

FODY

https://github.com/Fody/Fody

Extensible tool for weaving .net assemblies

Introduction

Manipulating the IL of an assembly as part of a build requires a significant amount of plumbing code. This plumbing code involves knowledge of both the MSBuild and Visual Studio APIs. Fody attempts to eliminate that plumbing code through an extensible add-in model.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [StaticProxy](https://github.com/BrunoJuchli/StaticProxy.Fody). very easy to use.